# Make button to be disabled initially, and enable if length of input is 10 in Angular

Tags: html, angular, typescript, button, enable-if

I have a requirement where I have to keep the button to be disabled initially and enable it only when the length of my input is 10.

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="MSISDN_Value" class="m-r-10">MSISDN:</label>
  <input type="number" 
    onkeyPress="if(this.value.length === 10) return false;" 
    [(ngModel)]="MSISDN_Value" 
    id="MSISDN_Value" 
    name="MSISDN_Value"
    class="form-control display-inline-block width70p m-b-5">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
  <button class="btn btn-primary m-l-65" type="submit" 
    [disabled]="true">Search</button>
</div>
```

I tried `[disabled] = "MSISDN_Value.length !== 10"`  but it did not work, there are many solutions that disable buttons, but I couldn't find any solution which enables buttons in Angular5.

Comment: maxlength="10" didn't worked, I tried it, that's why used, onkeyPress

Comment: Ah. It's type=number. Sorry about that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching, I took the help of events and used (input) function binding and fired an event on even.target.value changes to toggle [isDisabled]

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="MSISDN_Value" class="m-r-10">ISMSDN/IMEI:</label>
    <input type="number" onkeyPress="if(this.value.length === 10) return false;" (input)="onSearchChanges($event.target.value)" [(ngModel)]="MSISDN_Value" id="MSISDN_Value" name="MSISDN_Value" class="form-control display-inline-block width59p m-b-5">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <button class="btn btn-primary m-l-96" type="submit" [disabled]="searchDisabled">Search</button>
  </div>
```

component.ts file

```
onSearchChanges(value) {
    if(value.length === 10){
      this.searchDisabled = false;
    } else{
      this.searchDisabled = true;
    }
  }
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! If your code is working and solved your problem, please accept your own answer as an answer. This will help others when searching for similar questions to pick up yours, because searchers always try to look for questions that already have answers.

Comment: I cannot like my own answer, I have less reputation, can you like my answer, because it is working absolutely fine for me.

Comment: Anmol, I suggested you to [accept](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) your own answer, not like it. After doing that, comment my name here and I'll be back and upvote yours.

Answer (score 0):

Hii the problem is you are checking integer value with === operator which is returning false. see my below code.

```
<div class="form-group">
<label for="MSISDN_Value" class="m-r-10">MSISDN:</label>
<input type="number"
#num
max=10
(change)="toggle2($event)"  
id="MSISDN_Value" 
  name="MSISDN_Value"
  class="form-control display-inline-block width70p m-b-5">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<button class="btn btn-primary m-l-65" type="submit" 
  [disabled]="this.num.value==10?false:true">Search{{this.num.value===10}}</button>
</div>

//.ts file
toggle2(event){
  console.log(event.target.value)
}
```

Comment: (change)="toggle2($event)" doing here?, and how can I use this input value in ts file, if I am not using ([ngModel])?
Please like my question, I have less than 15 reputations, cannot like your answer either.